# Would running an ethereum node of a private network in android drain battery?

Tags: android, ethereum

I am building an android application where users can pay for items they buy with ether. Application will use a private ethereum network.

As I understood, I have to run an ethereum node in the android device as a separate process and my android app has to communicate with it using either sending commands or through JSON RPC.

Since android is very concerned about the power consumption, would android allow running a separate process continuously? Would android kill the process after some time?

Also, would running the node continuously in the device cause a huge battery drain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would. You have basicly two options, create a centralized server/client setup, where you android app does JSON RPC queries to a HttpProvider which you set up for your specific app, or you run a light client.

I think, the way to go is to run a light client ([LES protocol](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-%28LES%29)) which only connects to a full node if required. The light clients are currently heavily developed and there is some beta testing going on already.

Check out the [light client roadmap](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/225/87). In june the light client testing was opened to the public. You can test it by [running a fork of the go-ethereum client](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Client-Public-Test).

> - `git clone -b light-stable https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum.git`
> - build it with Go 1.6 (won't compile with earlier versions)
> - add the `--light` flag for light client mode (run `geth --light console` for console mode)
> - you can also run it on the testnet by specifying the `--testnet` flag or the original unforked "classic" chain with the `--oppose-dao-fork` flag
> - you can run the light client with the same (default) data directory you use with the normal client, it uses a separate "lightchaindata" database directory instead of the standard "chaindata" so it won't interfere with your regular chain database (can't run the two simultaneously with the same datadir though).
> - initial syncing starts from a trusted checkpoint (later this will be implemented in a trustless way). Past headers are still accessible on-demand. Trusted checkpoints are hardcoded into the source both for the mainnet and testnet.

There is a dedicated [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ethereum/light-client) where you can ask questions.